# Caching Firebase data for multiple collections - how can I know when anything has changed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase to allow users to save certain information about their logged-in profiles. In total I have 4 different collections, and all of which contain UID-matching documents.

When my site loads up, I need to immediately access data from all 4 collections for a given user's UID. This means that right now, whenever a user reloads my application they generate 4 get requests. However users of my application tend to not change their stored information very often (perhaps once every 20 or so times they load the application), so there's really no need for this data to be re-requested every time.

I've already taken steps to cache all of this data within the user's browser local storage, but here is where my problem lays: how can I know when the data I have cached is out of date?

In the past I've created similar cache mechanisms which ultimately rely on a 'version' flag. Both the data source and the user's local storage contain a 'version'. When both match, the application knows that it has the latest data, however when they are out of sync, the application knows it needs to re-request the data. The 'version' flag on the data source is ultimately changed every time an update occurs which impacts the user in question.

Ideally I want to end up with this flow:

1. User loads application.
2. Application compares local data version with version contained in Firebase.

   1. If versions match, use local data.
   2. If versions do not match, request all data.

Is it possible to do something like this with Firebase? Right now I can't see this possible without having to generate an extra set call every time the user's data is modified to change this version flag.

If this isn't possible, how can I know when a user's data needs updating without using up multiple requests?

If it helps, I'm using Firestore and this is a web application with no backend.

Comment: Can't you simply clear the localStorage upon data change, and then, if it is empty, reload it? ... I mean, and assume, you are in control of data updates, hence will know when those happens

Comment: @LGSon locally yes, that's fine. The issue is that a user could log in from different devices. If they changed a property on their mobile device, it should reflect on their laptop, for instance. I don't know how I can determine whether the data has changed without having to first request each of the 4 collections, or alternatively execute a set on the collection and on a separate version collection every time data updates.

Comment: Firestore's built-in offline persistence should manage all this for you.  Does it not work the way you expect?  You normally shouldn't have to implement your own cache.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline